# rust x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu using 'target-feature=+crt-static' exits with: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: rust, glibc, static-linking, coredump

I use `RUSTFLAGS='-C target-feature=+crt-static' cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.

I expected to see this happen: complied program with static linking runs normally.

Instead, this happened:

- when I debug, it exits with: Stop reason: signal SIGSEGV: invalid
  address (fault address: 0xe5)
- when I run the executable directly, it exits with: Segmentation fault
  (core dumped)

But when I debug the executable without static linking, `cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`, it works well. And when I build with `RUSTFLAGS='-C target-feature=+crt-static' cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl`, it works well, too.

This is the repo: https://github.com/noonuid/tat-agent/tree/w-who. The problem branch is the w-who, and the key source code in the folder `src/conpty`.

Command to run the executable: `target/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/tat_agent -c -n -p`. `-p` indicates the agent to work as pty server which makes developer can connect to it using the client code which locates in `tests/pty.html`.

I think others cannot run the executable as it needs to run in a particular environment.

Comment: Can you run the program through `gdb` to see exactly when and where it crashes?

Comment: You can do `gdb /path/to/program`, then type `r<enter>`, and it should crash. After the crash, you can do `bt<enter>` to display the backtrace which might contain good information.

Comment: Here you can see the backtrace: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/100110#issue-1327471412

Comment: Here is a similar problem: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/100711.

Comment: Did you find a way to this issue? @morningnoon

Comment: Not yet. I have created an issue: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/100110 from the rust repo. @FredHors